# barcode does not appear in print

Tags: html, css, barcode

I made my barcode and I can see in my html.

[image: Barcode is showing]

But when I want to print my page, my barcode will hide.

[image]

here is my html:

```
<div barcode-generator="{{fData.BillID}}{{fData.PaymentID}}" style="height: 30px; display: inline-block !important;">
        </div>
```

I'm using angularjs and javascript for making my barcode data.
What should I do, to make this barcode appear in print?

Comment: Thanks Sir for edit.

Comment: What library are you using for barcode generation?

Comment: If you hit the "More Settings" option in the print window and pick "Background Graphics", does it appear? It may be showing up as a background image which aren't always printed (browser dependent)

Comment: I did already. Nothing happened

Comment: @reinder: I'm using barcodeGenerator.js

Comment: That is a bit unspecific. Any file can be called barcodeGenerator.js. Why not post a fiddle to demonstrate your problem

Comment: @reinder: will send in next few minutes.